# Get for loop exception from net helpmsg

Tags: vbscript, error-code

I am making a console vbs script that does a for loop whilst running the following command:

```
NET Helpmsg #
```

'#' means the error code, so the script must count from 0 to 9999 then write each error as well as its error code into a text file.

My question is how do I tell cscript to ignore the following output of the net helpmsg command:

```
%1 is not a valid Windows network message number.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 3871.
```

This means that the error code does not exist and I would want to have this error ignored and therefore not added to the txt file. Is there some way to do this?

I am able to redirect STDOUT and STDERR to two seperate text files, however when doing this you have to know which error codes don't exist then tell them to manually go to stderr.txt.

Comment: There is no need to do such a thing. The Windows system error codes are [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @tomalak that is not OS specific, not every error exists from that web page in certain versions of windows.

Comment: I see. How about a cmd.exe one-liner? `for /l %i in (1,1,999) do @net helpmsg %i 1>NUL 2>&1 && echo %i & net helpmsg %i | findstr /i "[a-z]"`

Comment: @tomalak I ran this script and I get the following error: "i was unexpected at this time"

Comment: This works on the command line directly. Inside a batch file, you must use double percent signs (like `%%i`) with `for` loops. This is due to how batch files are parsed. Compare http://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html

Comment: @tomalak this runs now, how do I add the outputs to a text file?

Comment: Command line redirection. http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html

Comment: @tomalak ah right, so I added that to the end of the script and it works. Any way to add the error numbers to the text file as well?

Comment: The easiest way to achieve this is to put that line with the loop into a separate batch file and then `call` that file, redirecting the entire output of the loop into a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like that into a batch file :

```
@echo off
If Exist HelpLog.txt Del HelpLog.txt
(
    for /l %%i in (1,1,999) do @net helpmsg %%i 1>NUL 2>&1 && echo %%i & net helpmsg %%i | findstr /i "[a-z]"
)>> HelpLog.txt
Start "" HelpLog.txt
pause
```

Comment: Is there a way to have the numbers on the same line as the helpmsgs in the txt file, currently the numbers appear on their own lines. There would need to be a space to seperate the number from the helpmsg if it is possible to put them on one line each